# Alternative to csv delimited elements in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, prototype

Is there another away to append a bunch of elements together in array besides the following

```
var qtys = $$('#super-product-table .qty, #super-product-table-1 .qty, #super-product-table-2 .qty');
```

I want a alternative to getting the above array elements. for some reason IE 9 returns null but it works fine in google chrome and firefox.

Comment: Why tag jQuery if you're asking about prototypejs?

Comment: `var qtys = $('[id^=super-product-table]').find('.qty');`?